# how to create a SVN branch based on comments?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging

I want to have all the files which are modified for a particular requirement , I always have unique comment or CR number for all related check-in.
can i create the branch based on the comments ? so that i can only get the file which are modified for a particular requirement.

Comment: Branching individual files and not a whole directory structure is going to make for a huge pain/mess when you need to merge back to trunk or another branch. Can you do it? Yes, with a bunch of scripting. Is it recommended? I wouldn't do it.

Comment: i just want to create branch based on comments, there is no need to merge it back . please assist if you know how to do that?